# How to apply a permutation with repeated values on another

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, permutation

Consider the algorithm:

```
apply(src, perm) {
    result = []

    for (i; i < perm.length; i++) {
        result.push(src[perm[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

By passing a `src = [0,1,2,3]` and `perm = [3,0,1,2]` we get, in each iteration:

```
result -> 3
result -> 3 0
result -> 3 0 1
result -> 3 0 1 2
```

if we call `apply` with that result like `apply(result, perm)`, we get:

```
result -> 2 
result -> 2 3
result -> 2 3 0
result -> 2 3 0 1
```

And so on. Note that if we perform this the times of length of the arrays it will becomes to original state.

However, I need to perform this operation when exists repeated values, where each repeated value will represent the same element for my program. For example:

```
- applying the perm (2 0 [1 1]) in src (0 [1 1] 2) should result in (2 0 [1 1]);
- applying the perm (2 0 [1 1]) in src (2 0 [1 1]) should result in (1] 0 2 [1);
- applying the perm (2 0 [1 1]) in src (1] 0 2 [1) should result in ([1 1] 0 2);
- ...
```

I reduced the number of elements in arrays to make examples better, but actually the inputs will be in length of `12` (0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7). Furthermore, is not a just cyclic rotation; if the perm is different I think the results will work different as well. Also, always the repeated values will be only the `odd` and `even` numbers are single.

I tried to write a function that attempts to check something like if current value is odd or even, if odd pushes the next:

```
function apply(src, perm){
    res = [];
    last = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < perm.length; i++){
        if (src[perm[i]] % 2 === 0 && src[perm[i]] !== last){
            res.push(src[perm[i]]);
            last = src[perm[i]];
        } else if (src[perm[i]] % 2 === 0 && src[perm[i]] === last) {
            res.push(src[perm[i] + 1]);
            last = src[perm[i] + 1];
        } else {
            if (src[perm[i] + 1] !== undefined){ //out of bounds
                res.push(src[perm[i] + 1]);
                last = src[perm[i] + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here go some examples of inputs and its expected outputs:

```
base formula (no repetitions): result[i] = src[perm[i]]

Example 1:
src:    [4 1 1 2 5 5 0 3 3 6 7 7];
perm:   [4 1 1 6 3 3 0 5 5 2 7 7];
result: [0 1 1 6 5 5 4 3 3 2 7 7];

Example 2:
src:    [6 1 1 0 3 3 4 5 5 2 7 7];
perm:   [2 1 1 6 3 3 4 5 5 0 7 7];
result: [0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7];

Example 3:
src:    [0 1 1 2 3 3 6 5 5 4 7 7];
perm:   [2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 0 1 1];
result: [2 3 3 6 5 5 4 7 7 0 1 1];

Example 4:
src:    [2 1 1 6 5 5 4 3 3 0 7 7];
perm:   [1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 0];
result: [1 1 6 5 5 4 5 5 0 7 7 2];

Example 5:
src:    [6 7 7 0 1 1 4 5 5 2 3 3];
perm:   [3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 0 1 1 2];
result: [1 1 4 5 5 2 3 3 6 7 7 0];
```

Anyway, this doesn't work. I hope the question was clear, if not, feel free to ask anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have some examples of the last kind and the wanted results?

Comment: Of course @NinaScholz. I updated the question above.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense:

```
perm (2 0 [1 1]) in src (0 [1 1] 2) result is (2 0 [1 1])
```

But from this on, don't make sense anymore:

```
perm (2 0 [1 1]) in src (2 0 [1 1]) result is (1] 0 2 [1)
```

Let's see: First you take element `2` = `[1 1]`, or `1`, then element `0` = `2`, then element `[1 1]` = `0`, or `0, 0`. The result will never be `[1 0 2 1]`

So what I believe you need is `perm` with only the indexes without the repetitions:

```
perm (2 0 1) in src (0 [1 1] 2) result is (2 0 [1 1])
perm (2 0 1) in src (2 0 [1 1]) result is ([1 1] 2 0)
perm (2 0 1) in src ([1 1] 2 0) result is (0 [1 1] 2)
```

Which also gives you the cyclic property.

Assuming this answers your problem, you need to first remove the repetitions, and while constructing the result, readd the duplicates.

UPDATE: If your perm have repetitions, also remove those before running the algorythm.

```js
function removeDuplicates(arr) { // Assumes duplicates are in order
  var result = [], prev = null;
  for (var el of arr) {
    if (el != prev) result.push(el);
    prev = el;
  }
  return result;
}

function apply(src, perm) {
  var result = [], prev = null;
  var src2 = removeDuplicates(src);
  for (var i of perm) {
    if (i != prev) { // Ignore duplicates
      var el = src2[i];
      result.push(el);
      if (el % 2 != 0) result.push(el); // duplicate odds
    }
    prev = i;
  }
  console.log(`src = [${src}] perm = [${perm}] result = [${result}]`);
}

apply([0, 1, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]);
apply([2, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1]);
apply([1, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1]);

apply([4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 0, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7], [4, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 0, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7]);
apply([6, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7], [2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 7, 7]);
apply([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, 7], [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 0, 1, 1]);
apply([2, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 0, 7, 7], [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 0]);
apply([6, 7, 7, 0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 0, 1, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. And yes, I gave only few examples but now I just updated some new ones. However, I think your answer already solves the problem. Anyway, feel free to try something different if you want.

Comment: I guess if you use the perm with repetitions, but apply the same filter that remove duplicates over perm, it will work for your examples

Comment: Of course! And what about complexity? Unfortunatelly the filtering seems to take some extra time if calling this in a large amount of data.

Comment: Changed remove duplicates function to a much faster one.